# How to assign segue identifier and unwind segue to programmatically created viewcontrollers

Tags: swift

I've created my `ViewController` programmatically and I can use it as such:

```
let myVC = CustomViewController(style: .Plain)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(myVC, animated: true)
```

but is it possible to assign a segue identifier to it?
also, how do i assign a unwind segue(with identifier) to it...?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, segues cannot be created programmatically, instead, the storyboard runtime creates them when it must perform a segue between two view controllers.

So segues must be created from the storyboard itself. even the class shows: `UIStoryboardSegue`

For `unwinding`, since you pushed it into view, you could use `dismissViewControllerAnimated` to dismiss it out of view.

```
dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```